# Is there a smalltalk "toString" equivalent?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

For example, let's say I am adding a set of objects I created, called `myClass` (which contains a string) to `myList` and then I wish to use the list and pass it to a GUI list. Is there a way to populate that GUI list only with the value of that string in `myClass`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every object should respond to `printString` message with some meaningful string presentation of itself. You can write your own #printString for your object and use it.

Even better for your case could be implementation of `asString` conversion method, which converts your object to a string.

Comment: So, basically, as long as I defined my own printString method in my class, the GUI list will call that when passing a list of my objects?

Comment: This depends on the implementation of GUI framework. Which Smalltalk dialect you use?

Comment: In VisualWorks displayString is the way to define string representation of an object for GUIs, while printString is for debugger and inspector.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the methods you are looking for are printString and/or displayString.

Comment: So, basically, as long as I defined my own printString method in my class, the GUI list will call that when passing a list of my objects?

Comment: you want to override `self printOn: aStream` in your class.  `printString` will call that.